# MongoDB: Update field number with inverse value?

Tags: javascript, mysql, mongodb

My sitiuation is: I have a document in collection Users, example:

```
Users : {
  _id : "id_str",
  active : 1
}
```

I want to update `active` status of this user with `only one query`, like:

```
Users.update({
    _id : "id_str"
}, {
   $set : {
      active : 0 if active now is 1, 1 if active now is 0
   }
})
```

I'm not looking for any solution that find `user document` to get `active` status and then update it. I only want to use 1 query for resolve this problem

In the MySQL, I often resolve this problem within only one SQL:

`UPDATE users SET active = ABS(active - 1) WHERE...`

But I dont know how do it in MongoDB. Please help me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with [`$bit`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/bit/#up._S_bit) and the `xor` operator, but you need to ensure that your values are integers and not doubles as they default to in the shell.

So if you create your docs as:

```
db.users.insert([{
  _id : "id_str1",
  active : NumberInt(0)
},{
  _id : "id_str2",
  active : NumberInt(1)
}])
```

You can toggle their `active` values using:

```
db.users.update({}, {$bit: {active: {xor: NumberInt(1)}}}, {multi: true})
```